# DataGridView Filter not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter

I know there are a good few threads on this topic but i have tried everything and still no luck filtering my datagridview. I am trying to filter the rows of a datagridview based on the value a user inputs in a text field. The datagridviews datasource is set du the datasource provided below.

So here is the code i am using. i get no errors, the datagridview simply does not change.
ManufacturerService.GettAll returns a List of Manufacturer, i convert it to a bindinglist to

`bsManufacturers.DataSource = new BindingList<Manufacturer>(ManufacturerService.GetAll(_ctx));`

On the textchanged event of the textbox this code runs. i have checked with breakpoints and so on. the code is executed ant the filter string is correct.

```
private void FilterData(string str)
{
    bsManufacturers.Filter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", str);
    dgvManufacturers.Refresh();
}
```

Any help? or atleast an explanation of why this does not work? I have been working on this for a good few hours and just cant seem to find an anwser anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using this project:
http://blw.sourceforge.net/

Personally i think there should be a better way of doing this but it's working now and i guess that i will have to be happy with "good enough" for now.

Here is the working code. The important parts anyway.

```
private void PopulateDataGridView()
{
     blvManufacturers = new BindingListView<Manufacturer>(ManufacturerService.GetAll(_ctx));
    _bsManufacturers = new BindingSource { DataSource = _blvManufacturers};
    dgvManufacturers.DataSource = _bsManufacturers;         
}

private void FilterData(string str)
{
    // Change the filter of the view.
      blvManufacturers.ApplyFilter(
        delegate(Manufacturer manu)
        {
            // uses ToLower() to ignore case of text.
            return manu.Name.ToLower().Contains(str.ToLower());
        }
    );           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

data sorting information is contained in grid headers. Users may set single or multiple sorting in one or multiple headers. On programming level, sorting looks as follows

```
//Get top-level header
Header header = grid.Headers[0];

header["Product"].SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
header["Price"].SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
```

Setting `Column.Sortable` property to false is sufficient to enable software-only sorting preventing users from modifying it via UI dapfor. com

Answer (score 0):

There is a Library that create Filter on datagrid view:

[DataGridView Filter Popup](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup)

Regards

Comment: tried this and also setting dgv datasource to null beofre setting it to the bindingsource. while i break and check the properties of the bindingsource the Filter property is set correctly but still the datagridview is not filtered

Comment: ok so i have found that the prop SupportsFiltering = false.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.supportsfiltering.aspx   i still cant understand why though. should BindingList not implement this interface?

Comment: @user782838 BindingList doesn't implement any filtering at all. All the filtering is done in the BindingSource.

Comment: so how can i accomplish getting the SupportsFiltering prop to true?

Comment: Is (ManufacturerService.GetAll(_ctx)) populating the datasource for the Binding List when you are debugging?

Comment: yes it is. I am looking into using http://blw.sourceforge.net/ . got into some trouble getting the object selected in the dgv with it though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to be using a Binding List for this, you may be better off using a DataTable as the datasource for a "Binding Source".

Then you could use the following in you FilterData Method :-

```
DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.format("Name like '%{0}%'", str);
```

You would set it up like this :-

```
Binding Source.Datasource = DataTable,
DatagridView.Datasource = Binding Source;
```

If you do this, you wont even have to refresh you datatgrid, it will do it automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not try this yet. this i would have to write code to convert my bindinglist or generic List to a DataTable first.

Comment: What does ManufacturerService.GetAll(_ctx) actually do?